# Roku: How to hide Overhang using XML

Tags: xml, roku, brightscript

I am using the Roku Scene Graph XML to create my screen. I currently have an overhang on the top of my screen that I would like to slide out after 5 seconds of not being focused on it. The Roku Docs make it seem like this is possible, but don't give a way to do it. Anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @RenjithVR appreciate the effort, I solved my problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find useful [this](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Animation+Markup) tutorial about how animation works in Roku Scene Graph.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check this out

Comment: It seems like this action isn't built in and it makes the on event key handling not smooth at all. Just a heads up for anyone trying the same thing.